# Using disconnect function on socket.io and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to have it so when a user disconnects from my chat room, it pops up with " has left chat room".

Here is my server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('chat/index.html');
});




io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(nickname){
   io.emit('disconnect', nickname);
  });

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And here is my client code:

```
var socket = io();
  var nickname;
  var leaving;

  $('messageForm').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', (nickname + ": " + $('#m').val()));
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });

  $('#nicknameForm').submit(function(){

   nickname = $('#nickname').val();

   if(nickname ==''){
  alert("Please enter a value");
  }else{
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
   leaving = nickname + " has left";
    }
    return false;
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });


   socket.on('disconnect', function(nickname){
    socket.emit('disconnect message', nickname);
  });
```

At the moment, nothing appears at all, and I'm not too sure why.

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm not familiar with `node.js` or `socket.io` but it doesn't seem to me like your client is actually disconnecting. Have you checked to see if you can forcefully disconnect in order to trigger the event?

Comment: It is definitely disconnecting because I am closing the browser window.

Comment: Are you expecting the message on the client or server? edit - scratch that, more importantly, have you tried it with two clients, one listening on the chat room while the other disconnects, or are you trying with a single client?

Comment: On the client. Tried it with multiple clients to no avail.

Comment: Is it possible that it only considers it a disconnect after the _last_ client disconnects? Might help to see what the _server-side_ script thinks is happening if you're not already monitoring it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit a unique event to the clients when another client disconnects.

Change the following:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  io.emit('disconnect', nickname);
});
```

To something like this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  socket.broadcast.emit('user disconnect', nickname);
});
```

And add this to your client code:

```
socket.on('user disconnect', function(nickname){
  $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(nickname+' has left the channel.'));
});
```